# What's the difference between mtpfs and jmtpfs packages in Debian?

Tags: debian, mtp, smartphone

I recently wanted to connect some LG Android smartphone to my Debian, but the device wasn't detected. I installed the `jmtpfs` package, and that solved the problem. But in Debian, you have two packages with similar names: `mtpfs` and `jmtpfs`. What's the difference between the two? [On the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp#libmtp) there's info that the `mtpfs` was orphaned a long time ago. Is that the only thing, and that's why I should prefer `jmtpfs` over `mtpfs`, or is there something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's precisely it! If a package is orphaned and another has taken its place you almost always want to go with the non-orphaned one for support, updates etc.

In this specific example, as the wiki page you linked says, the only real differences are the name and package status.